# Test if it exists a node HXT

Tags: haskell, if-statement, attributes, arrows, hxt

Is there a way to test a node (Attribute Value) and use it with my if-condition ?
For example:

```
import Text.XML.HXT.Core
import System.Environment  --para uso do getArgs
import Data.List.Split (splitOn)

data Class = Class { name ::String }
    deriving (Show,Eq)

main = do
   [src]<- getArgs
   teams <- runX(readDocument [ withValidate no] src  >>> getClass)
   print teams
--Test
test = if (True) then getAttrValue "rdf:about" else getAttrValue "rdf:ID"

atTag tag = deep (isElem >>> hasName tag)
getClass = atTag "owl:Class" >>>
    proc l -> do
    className <- test -< l
    returnA -< Class { name = splitOn "#" className !! 1}
```

On that example, i would like to test an attribute value and if it exists it return my then-condition otherwise the else-condition !
I saw the API of XMLArrow and it exists some function which will be able to do it (for example, isAttrib or hasAttrib) But it doesn't return a boolean ...
So ... I thought on other ways for solving it, but i think there must be a simpler solution to solve that...
Can someone gives me a hint please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the functions of the module [Control.Arrow.ArrowIf](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hxt-9.3.1.3/docs/Control-Arrow-ArrowIf.html) of the hxt package. Here you find the function [ifA](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hxt-9.3.1.3/docs/Control-Arrow-ArrowIf.html#v%3aifA), a lifted version of the if-else-statement. For example the code

```
if (True) then getAttrValue "rdf:about" else getAttrValue "rdf:ID"
```

should be written as

```
ifA (constA True) (getAttrValue "rdf:about") (getAttrValue "rdf:ID")
```

Depending of what you want to archive, you should use derived functions of `ifA` like [guards](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hxt-9.3.1.3/docs/Control-Arrow-ArrowIf.html#v%3aguards).

Comment: what i want ,is to test if it exists a node with attribute "rdf:about", if it does exists then take the value from there ! Otherwise, test if it exists the node with ref:ID attribute ! And if it it exists , return the value of that attribute !

Comment: I think i made it ! :) Thank you ! :)